# link_to with jquery params in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, link-to, in-place

I want to make an in-place search in my rails app.
I used button_to_remote with prototype, but now I'm using JQuery, so I changed to link_to.
This is my code:

```
<%= link_to "Search", {:action => "geocode", :with => "'address='+$('#{address_helper_id}').value"}, :method => :post, :remote => true %>
```

I want to pass the address textfield to my controller, but the output is not what I expected.

```
/mycontroller/geocode?with=%27address%3D%27%2B%24%28%27record_location___address%27%29.value
```

How do I submit my value?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to try approaching things a little more unobtrusively. I would recommend replacing your `link_to` call with something like:

```
<%= link_to "Search", "#", :id => "search_geocode", :"data-href" => my_controller_geocode_path %>
```

This is virtually identical to what you already have, except that it includes a unique id, and also the controller/geocode path in an `data-href` attribute. This will help allow you to keep your ruby and javascript a bit more separated.

Then in your `application.js` (or somewhere similar):

```
$('#search_geocode').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('data-href') + "?address=" + $('#address').val(), function(data){} );
});
```

What this is effectively doing is binding a `click` event listener to your search button, which posts the address to the url or path provided in the `data-href` attribute of your search link.

I also notice that in your code, you're setting the `id` of the source address in ruby. If this `id` attribute needs to change based on some sort of page template conditions, you could expand on my example by adding another `data-` parameter to your link. For example:

```
<%= link_to "Search", "#", :id => "search_geocode", :"data-href" => my_controller_geocode_path, :"data-address-id" => address_helper_id %>
```

And again, in `application.js` replacing above with something along the lines of:

```
$('#search_geocode').live('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('data-href') + "?address=" + $($(this).attr('data-address-id')).val(), function(data){} );
});
```

Comment: attention: I think .live is deprecated. Look below.
$( selector ).live( events, data, handler );                // jQuery 1.3+
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
in this link: https://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to put the search field and the submit button in a normal form (using the default rails view helpers). And you add the `:remote => :true` option to the form. See [form_for url helper](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/3.0.0/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper%3aform_for) for the docs.

I gueuss you already added the jquery specific rails.js file.

Doing it like this will automatically post the form via ajax to the given action.

After that, you only need a 'ajax:success' event handler so that you can handle the data.

```
$('<id of the form').bind('ajax:success', function(event, data, status, xhr) {
   ... process your data here ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

`<%= text_field_tag :address %>`
`<%= submit_tag "Search", :id => "search_button" %>`

```
### Paste following code in your javascript

$("#search_button").live("click", function(){
  $.ajax({
    complete:function(request){},
    data:'address='+ $('#address').val(),
    dataType:'script',
    type:'get',
    url: '[ROUTE TO ACTION]' // in your case, may be '/[CONTROLLER NAME]/geocode' until you define route
  })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't exactly a direct answer to your question, but have you looked into [jrails](https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails)? It allows you to use the same prototype javascript helpers that you were using before you switched over to jquery. It made my transition from prototype to jquery *much* easier.