# Rails 3 upgrade link_to :remote :with options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm upgrading to Rails 3, and replacing all my link_to_remote calls with link_to(..., :remote => true).  However, I'm trying to figure out how to implement the :with option in Rails 3.  The :with option is a way to supply a on-the-fly query param using javascript variables.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has been removed from Rails 3, as it goes against the principle of non-obstrusive javascript.

So, you should try to find another way to achieve whatever you want....

Take a look here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: Right, I've looked at all those resources, but none of them really tells me how to carry over the :with concept...

Comment: A good example of how approach in an unobtrusively way can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292508/link-to-with-jquery-params-in-rails)

Comment: I guess there's no convention, everything is just custom...Thanks!